# How do I simply get geolocation from a webapp?

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

I dont have an HTTPS application, so trying the Here.com api as an alternative.

Its basic c# asp.net web application. I just need to track the location of the user using the web application.

Ideally, it would intermittently call an API to get location co-ords and then I can store it in my DB.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

As per Google's policy, starting from Chrome 50 the Geolocation API only works on secure contexts (HTTPS). If your site is hosted on a non-secure origin (such as HTTP), any requests for the user's location no longer function. You can test your application on localhost but ultimately on production you will be needing HTTPS endpoint.

Please refer to this link - https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/user-location